# using one query values in another query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

```
// To get current user id
var currentUsrId = Convert.ToInt16(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey); 

var IDquery = My_usr_contacts_requests.Where(i => i.requests_to_usr_id == currentUsrId)
                                      .Select(i => new { i.from_usr_id })
                                      .ToArray();

var mainquery = My_usr_biographic_details
                   .Join(
                       My_usr_profiles_companies, i => i.usr_id, j => j.company_usr_id,
                       (i, j) => new
                                 {
                                     usr_id = j.company_usr_id,
                                 })
                   .Where(i =>IDquery.contains(i.usr_id))
                   .ToArray();
```

while I am executing I am getting array of values in `IDquery`, and I want to use these values in the where condition of mainquery as shown above, but when I give like this it showing error at the mainquery where condition. Can you tell me how to use the array of values retrieved from `IDquery` in `mainquery`?

Comment: What is the error? You use only Contains so it should be fine. (Maybe you have a syntax error since you wrote "contains")

Comment: no actually,IDquery is an array type,so when i use contains in where clause of main query,IDquery is array type and i.profiles_company_usr_id is an int type,so thats why it is showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
var IDquery = dbContext.My_usr_contacts_requests.Where(i => 
    i.Usr_contacts_requests_to_usr_id==currentUsrId).Select(i => new { 
    i.Usr_contacts_requests_from_usr_id }).ToArray();
```

The last new is unnecessary. It creates an array of arrays. You need to change it to:

```
var IDquery = dbContext.My_usr_contacts_requests.Where(i => 
    i.Usr_contacts_requests_to_usr_id==currentUsrId).Select(i => 
    i.Usr_contacts_requests_from_usr_id).ToArray();
```